# Set Session Expiry - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

I have an application in which I used the tutorial offered by http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app?version=3.0#sec:planning_the_application and http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-signin_failure (Rails 3.2) to create my user and session model.

I want to implement a expiration if user is in-active for 5 minutes or so. I have tried:

```
config.timeout_in = 5.minutes in my **application.rb**
```

and

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'blanked_out', :expire_after => 2.minutes in my **session_store.rb**
```

None of these seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

**Sessions Helper**

```
def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  self.current_user = user
end

def sign_out
  self.current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try this?

EDIT:

```
MAX_SESSION_TIME = {enter time}

before_filter :verify_session

def verify_session

   if !session[:expire].nil? and session[:expire] < Time.now
      # Session has expired. Clear or reset session.
      reset_session
   end

   # Assign a new expiry time, whether the session has expired or not.
   session[:expire] = MAX_SESSION_TIME.seconds.from_now
   return true
end
```

Comment: in your controller you can define a method expire_session with that line and then set a before_filter :expire_session with except params where u don't want it to be included.

Comment: Still a no-go. Nothing seems to be working in the attempt to expire a session and force user logout

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following while researching a CookieStore issue.  I think it answers your question:

https://www.coffeepowered.net/2013/09/26/rails-session-cookies/

Here's the code Chris Heald suggests for adding session timeout with CookieStore (note this would go in your application_controller.rb file:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :validate_session_timestamp
  after_filter  :persist_session_timestamp

  SESSION_TTL = 48.hours
  def validate_session_timestamp
    if user? && session.key?(:ttl) && session[:ttl] < SESSION_TTL.ago
      reset_session
      current_user = nil
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

  def persist_session_timestamp
   session[:ttl] = Time.now if user?
  end
end
```

Comment: You might want to add some details from the link to your answer.